# My sudo apt install command is weird after following some instruction

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, libraries

I'm using WSL and I want to download libpng. And so, initially I typed:

```
sudo apt -y install libpng-dev
```

and it worked until it returned cannot access archive.ubuntu or something like that (I don't remember the exact output since it happened like a couple of hours ago)

So, naturally, I went to google to see how to fix this. I stumbled upon a question that asked relatively similar things to what I'm experiencing. So I just followed the most upvoted answer (Again, I can't recall which question was that or what the most upvoted answer was).

I think I may have typed these `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list` `sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M" -O /etc/apt/sources.list` `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null`. one of these three or maybe a combination of them

And the next thing I know, whenever I run
`sudo apt ...`
I get a return like this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpng-dev
```

which is entirely different than what I used to had initially. How do I fix this??

Bonus question: How do I install libpng after that? I need to use

```
#include <png.h>
```

on C

Comment: Just checking since you don’t mention it; make sure to rerun ‘sudo apt update’

Comment: Also recommend checking your browser history to see if you can find the instructions you followed. It might be difficult to fix if we don’t know what you changed, of course ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds. I've ran that command before. It returned "everything is up to date". Anywho, I think I typed these ``` sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list ``` ```sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M" -O /etc/apt/sources.list``` ```echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null```. one of these three or maybe a combination of them... it'd be great if you could help me install libpng as well (please I need this to save my GPA)

Comment: I'm not really an expert in `apt`, so I'm not sure I'll be able to help.  Just trying to get things clarified so that someone can try to help.  I've edited the tags to that hopefully someone with `apt` expertise sees it.  Please make sure to [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507631/edit) your question and include the new information. It's best if all of the necessary information is in the question itself rather than the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the **complete** output of `sudo apt update`.